# Problem with UseEffect , this useEffect I am using runs infinitely even after all required data is fetched

Tags: reactjs

I have used useEffect as below to get the relevant Guide ID for a given Tour ID , the code works fine but the problem is that this runs infinitely causing the system to slow down.I know there is way to limit the iterations of this but I am not clear as to how to apply in this.

The useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
      bookings.forEach(({ tourId }) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/assignedGuides/check/${tourId}`).then((res) =>{
          if(res.data === true){
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/assignedGuides/get/${tourId}`)
            .then(res => {
              setGuides(guides => ({
                ...guides,
                [tourId]: res.data.guideId,
              }));
            })
          }

        })

      });
    }, [bookings]);
```

The code section the Tour ID is coming from.

```
 {bookings.map((booking) =>(
                            
                            <tr>
                                <th scope = "row">{number++}</th>
                                <td>{booking.tourId}</td>
                                <td>{booking.bookingDate}</td>
                                <td>{booking.arrivalDate}</td>
                                <td>{booking.country}</td>
                                {/* {GuideAssigned(booking.guideId)} */}
                                <td>{guides[booking.tourId]}</td>
```

useStates

```
   const [bookings , setBookings] = useState([]);
   const [guides, setGuides] = useState({});
```

Full Code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import IndexHeader from "components/Headers/IndexHeader";
import IndexNavbar from "components/Navbars/IndexNavbar";
import DemoFooter from "components/Footers/DemoFooter";
import {
  Label,
  Input,
  Button,
  Row,
  Col,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  FormGroup,
  Alert,
  Container,
} from "reactstrap";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";



function AssignGuide(){



    

   const [bookings , setBookings] = useState([]);
   const [guides, setGuides] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:8070/bookings/").then((res) =>{
            setBookings(res.data);
        })
    })

    let history = useHistory();
    var number = 1;
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if(bookings.length != 0) {
      bookings.forEach(({ tourId }) => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/assignedGuides/check/${tourId}`).then((res) =>{
          if(res.data === true){
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/assignedGuides/get/${tourId}`)
            .then(res => {
              setGuides(guides => ({
                ...guides,
                [tourId]: res.data.guideId,
              }));
            })
          }

        })
      
      });
    }
    },[bookings]);

    return(
        
        <div>
            <IndexNavbar />
            <IndexHeader />
            <h3 style ={{marginLeft:"40px"}}>Assigned Guides</h3><br/><br/>

            <Row>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <InputGroup style = {{marginLeft : "40px"}} className="form-group-no-border">
                <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                  <InputGroupText>
                    <i className="nc-icon nc-zoom-split" />
                  </InputGroupText>
                </InputGroupAddon>
                <Input placeholder="Search " type="text" 
/>
              </InputGroup>
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <div>
              <Label style = {{marginLeft : "40px"}} check>
                <Input type="checkbox"/>{" "} 
                <label style ={{marginRight : "40px"}}>Tour ID</label>
              </Label>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col></Col>
        </Row>

            <div style = {{marginLeft:"20px"}}  className = "tableContainer">
                <table className = "table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th scope = "col">#</th>
                        <th scope = "col">Tour ID</th>
                        <th scope = "col">Booking Date</th>
                        <th scope = "col">Arrival Date</th>
                        <th scope = "col">Country </th>
                        <th scope = "col">Guide Assigned </th>
                        <th scope = "col">Operation</th>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        
                        {bookings.map((booking) =>(
                            
                            <tr>
                                <th scope = "row">{number++}</th>
                                <td>{booking.tourId}</td>
                                <td>{booking.bookingDate}</td>
                                <td>{booking.arrivalDate}</td>
                                <td>{booking.country}</td>
                                {/* {GuideAssigned(booking.guideId)} */}
                                <td>{guides[booking.tourId]}</td>
                                <td><Button color="warning"  style = {{padding: "5px 5px 5px 5px" , width : "80px" , marginBottom : "8px"}}
                                onClick = {()=>{
                                    history.push(`/assign-guide/${booking.username}`);
                                }}
                                >Assign Guide</Button>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
    
                        ))}
                    </tbody>    


                </table>
            </div>   
            
            <DemoFooter />
        </div>    
    );

}

export default AssignGuide;
```

Thank you for taking time in going through this! Hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: Just add if condition before loop

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are or by mistake the value of bookings is constantly changing and as 'bookings' is an dependency array provided to useEffect it is runnung infinetely.

Please check where you used 'setBookings;.

Comment: @AyushSingh Thank you for the recommendation! I will check for it , and I have also posted the full code below , you can check it if possible.Thank you!

Comment: @KrushnasinhJadeja Thank you! Unfortunately does not seem to work, it is something wrong with the Booking I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple if check:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
      if(bookings.length === 0){
        axios.get("http://localhost:8070/bookings/").then((res) =>{
            setBookings(res.data);
        })
      }
    }, [bookings])
```

Or, making this call on the very first render only:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:8070/bookings/").then((res) =>{
            setBookings(res.data);
        })
    }, [])
```

Without the dependency array, you setBookings on every re-render which causes a re-render itself

Comment: Hello , Thank you very much for the idea , it should be != 0 right? I did so , Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I interpreted this wrong. Your code is not reproducible. Please edit your question and show everywhere you use `setBookings` and I will update the answer.

Comment: Okay , I have added the full code below in the post. Thank you!

Comment: Edited the answer, if check should be here, you were setting bookings on every re-render, resulting in an infinite renders

Comment: Happy coding! :)